# Can't wake POSIX thread using signal

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals, posix

I'm writing a multi-threaded program for a Linux target where one thread should only run when a SIGIO signal arrives from a UART. I have tested the code using no threads and only a signal handler which works fine but when i make it a thread something goes wrong.

The main creates two threads: GNSSThread and a TestThread.
The TestThread is just a while(1) that prints a sentence once a second.

I've tried playing with other signals and i can successfully make the code proceed from the sigwaitinfo() with a  ^C keyboard input. I think it might be in the way the UART file descriptor is configured?

Hope somebody can help.

Code below.

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << endl << "Process "<< argv[0] << " started with PID: " << getpid() << endl << endl;

    InitConfig();

    InitThreads();

    return 0;
}
```

ThreadFn.cpp

```
sigset_t SigSet;

void InitThreads() {
    pthread_t GNSSThreadID, TestThreadID;

    //Configuring serial port to send SIGIO signal when I/O data ready to this process
    fcntl(Config.GNSSDataLinkLayer->GetFD(), F_SETSIG, SIGIO);
    fcntl(Config.GNSSDataLinkLayer->GetFD(), F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);
    fcntl(Config.GNSSDataLinkLayer->GetFD(), F_SETOWN, getpid());

    //Config thread to receive SIGIO
    sigemptyset(&SigSet);
    sigaddset(&SigSet, SIGIO);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &SigSet, NULL);

    pthread_create(&GNSSThreadID, NULL, GNSSThreadFn, NULL);
    pthread_create(&TestThreadID, NULL, TestThreadFn, NULL);

    pthread_join(TestThreadID, NULL);
}

void *GNSSThreadFn(void *param) {
    cout << "Configuring GNSS Thread" << endl;
    siginfo_t SigInfo;
    mutex mtx;

    cout << "Entering GNSS Thread while loop" << endl;

    while(1){
        //Thread suspended until signal arrives
        cout << "Before sigwait" << endl;
        sigwaitinfo(&WaitSet, &SigInfo);
        cout << "After sigwait" << endl;

        //checking for correct file descriptor and if signal caused by send or receive
        if(SigInfo.si_fd == Config.GNSSDataLinkLayer->GetFD() && SigInfo.si_code == POLL_IN){
            cout << "GNSSThreadMaster::ThreadLoop: Serial port read" << endl;
            //Locking mutex while reading talker
            mtx.lock();
            Config.NMEATransportLayer->ReadTalker();
            mtx.unlock();
        }else if(SigInfo.si_fd == Config.GNSSDataLinkLayer->GetFD() && SigInfo.si_code == POLL_OUT){
            tcdrain(Config.GNSSDataLinkLayer->GetFD());
            //Magic sleep to make it work
            usleep(20000);
        }else
            cout << "ThreadLoop: Signal error" << endl;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Threads have individual masks for signals - so you'll have to have your GNSSThreadFn also register the signal mask.  Be aware that only 1 thread will ever get the signal; and there's no guarantee which if you have multiple threads listening with that mask.

Comment: What happens if you *block* rather than *unblock* the signals you are interested in, in all threads?  (See, e.g., the Notes from the [Linux `sigwaitinfo` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigwaitinfo).)